# Solving Pentomino puzzles by using Knuth's Algorithm X

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

I wrote a program which solves [Pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) puzzles by using [Knuth's Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X). My priorities were: readability, straightforwardness and brevity of the solution, so I didn't try to squeeze as much performance as possible by eliminating function calls in some places or similar tricks.

**I am interested in:**

1. The code review. How this code can be better?
2. Performance improvement. Do you see a way to increase performance? May be **numpy** can help here? At this moment the fastest version takes **1 hour 57 minutes** on **Intel i5-2500** to find all solutions of **5 x 12** board. The second version is slower by three times, but it is having less of code duplicity, so it is more beautiful in my opinion - what do you think?
3. Reducing a code duplicity of the faster version but without of large performance drop, as I have in my second version.

#### Usage:

**5 x 12 board**

```
rows = 5
cols = 12
board = [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
solver = Solver(board, figures, rows, cols, 1)
solver.find_solutions()
```

**Output** (partial - the first solution only)

```
The solution № 1
 12 12  5  5  5  5  8  8  7  7  7  7
  9 12 12 12  5  6  6  8  7 11  3  3
  9  9  9  2  6  6 10  8  8 11  3  3
  1  9  1  2  6 10 10 10 11 11 11  3
  1  1  1  2  2  2 10  4  4  4  4  4

####################################################################
```

**8 x 8 board with 4 prefilled cells in the middle.**

```
rows = 8
cols = 8
board = [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
board[3][3] = '#'
board[3][4] = '#'
board[4][3] = '#'
board[4][4] = '#'

solver = Solver(board, figures, rows, cols, 1)
solver.find_solutions()
```

**Output** (partial)

```
1614 variants have tried
Time has elapsed: 0:00:05.104412
The solution № 1
 12 12  4  4  4  4  4 11
  6 12 12 12  5 11 11 11
  6  6  5  5  5  5 10 11
  8  6  6  #  # 10 10 10
  8  8  8  #  #  9 10  7
  2  1  8  1  9  9  9  7
  2  1  1  1  3  3  9  7
  2  2  2  3  3  3  7  7

#################################################################
```

#### The program

The slower version's methods are commented out, remove comments to test it (and comment out corresponding methods of the first version).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from time import time
from datetime import timedelta

figures = {
            (
                (1,1,1,1,1),        
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1,1),      
                (1,0,0,0),      
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1,1),      
                (0,1,0,0),      
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1,0),      
                (0,0,1,1),      
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1),        
                (1,0,1),        
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1),        
                (0,1,1),        
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1),        
                (1,0,0),        
                (1,0,0)     
            ),
            (
                (1,1,0),        
                (0,1,1),        
                (0,0,1)     
            ),
            (
                (1,0,0),        
                (1,1,1),        
                (0,0,1)     
            ),
            (
                (0,1,0),        
                (1,1,1),        
                (1,0,0)     
            ),
            (
                (0,1,0),        
                (1,1,1),        
                (0,1,0)     
            ),
            (
                (1,1,1),        
                (0,1,0),        
                (0,1,0)     
            )
}

class Node():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.up = None
        self.down = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.row_head = None
        self.col_head = None

class Linked_list_2D():
    def __init__(self, width):
        self.width = width
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = left_neigh = right_neigh = up_neigh = down_neigh = new_node
        elif self.size % self.width == 0:
            up_neigh = self.head.up
            down_neigh = self.head
            left_neigh = right_neigh = new_node
        else:
            left_neigh = self.head.up.left
            right_neigh = left_neigh.right
            if left_neigh is left_neigh.up:
                up_neigh = down_neigh = new_node
            else:
                up_neigh = left_neigh.up.right
                down_neigh = up_neigh.down

        new_node.up = up_neigh
        new_node.down = down_neigh 
        new_node.left = left_neigh
        new_node.right = right_neigh
        # Every node has links to the first node of row and column
        # These nodes are used as the starting point to deletion and insertion
        new_node.row_head = right_neigh
        new_node.col_head = down_neigh

        up_neigh.down = new_node
        down_neigh.up = new_node
        right_neigh.left = new_node
        left_neigh.right = new_node

        self.size += 1

    def print_list(self, separator=' '):
        for row in self.traverse_node_line(self.head, "down"):
            for col in self.traverse_node_line(row, "right"):
                print(col.value, end=separator) 
            print()

    def traverse_node_line(self, start_node, direction):
        cur_node = start_node
        while cur_node:
            yield cur_node
            cur_node = getattr(cur_node, direction)
            if cur_node is start_node:
                break

### First approach - a lot of code duplicity
    def col_nonzero_nodes(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            if cur_node.value and cur_node.row_head is not self.head:
                yield cur_node
            cur_node = cur_node.down
            if cur_node is node:
                break

    def row_nonzero_nodes(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            if cur_node.value and cur_node.col_head is not self.head:
                yield cur_node
            cur_node = cur_node.right
            if cur_node is node:
                break

    def delete_row(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            up_neigh = cur_node.up
            down_neigh = cur_node.down

            if cur_node is self.head:
                self.head = down_neigh
                if cur_node is down_neigh:
                    self.head = None

            up_neigh.down = down_neigh
            down_neigh.up = up_neigh

            cur_node = cur_node.right
            if cur_node is node:
                break

    def insert_row(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            up_neigh = cur_node.up
            down_neigh = cur_node.down

            up_neigh.down = cur_node
            down_neigh.up = cur_node

            cur_node = cur_node.right
            if cur_node is node:
                break

    def insert_col(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            left_neigh = cur_node.left
            right_neigh = cur_node.right

            left_neigh.right = cur_node
            right_neigh.left = cur_node

            cur_node = cur_node.down
            if cur_node is node:
                break

    def delete_col(self, node):
        cur_node = node
        while cur_node:
            left_neigh = cur_node.left
            right_neigh = cur_node.right

            if cur_node is self.head:
                self.head = right_neigh
                if cur_node is right_neigh:
                    self.head = None

            left_neigh.right = right_neigh
            right_neigh.left = left_neigh

            cur_node = cur_node.down
            if cur_node is node:
                break

### Second approach - moving the common parts of code to separate functions.
### Then these functions are used in needed places, instead of duplicating the same code
### every time. But the perfomance was dropped by three times, so I decided to not use this
### methods in the program.
###
#   def delete_node(self, cur_node, a_node, a_neigh, b_node, b_neigh):
#       if cur_node is self.head:
#           self.head = b_node
#           if cur_node is b_node:
#               self.head = None
#       setattr(a_node, a_neigh, b_node)
#       setattr(b_node, b_neigh, a_node)
#       self.size -= 1
#
#   def insert_node(self, cur_node, a_node, a_neigh, b_node, b_neigh):
#       setattr(a_node, a_neigh, cur_node)
#       setattr(b_node, b_neigh, cur_node)
#       self.size += 1
#
#   def col_nonzero_nodes(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node.col_head, "down"):
#           if cur_node.value and cur_node.row_head is not self.head:
#               yield cur_node
#
#   def row_nonzero_nodes(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node.row_head, "right"):
#           if cur_node.value and cur_node.col_head is not self.head:
#               yield cur_node
#
#   def delete_row(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node, "right"):
#           self.delete_node(cur_node, cur_node.up, "down", cur_node.down, "up")
#
#   def delete_col(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node, "down"):
#           self.delete_node(cur_node, cur_node.left, "right", cur_node.right, "left")
#
#   def insert_row(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node, "right"):
#           self.insert_node(cur_node, cur_node.up, "down", cur_node.down, "up")
#
#   def insert_col(self, node):
#       for cur_node in self.traverse_node_line(node, "down"):
#           self.insert_node(cur_node, cur_node.left, "right", cur_node.right, "left")

class Solver():
    def __init__(self, board, figures, rows, cols, figures_naming_start):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.fig_name_start = figures_naming_start
        self.figures = figures
        self.solutions = set()
        self.llist = None
        self.start_board = board
        self.tried_variants_num = 0

    def find_solutions(self):
        named_figures = set(enumerate(self.figures, self.fig_name_start))
        all_figure_postures = self.unique_figure_postures(named_figures)

        self.llist = Linked_list_2D(self.rows * self.cols + 1)
        pos_gen = self.generate_positions(all_figure_postures, self.rows, self.cols)

        for line in pos_gen:
            for val in line:
                self.llist.append(val)
        self.delete_filled_on_start_cells(self.llist)

        self.starttime = time()
        self.prevtime = self.starttime
        self.dlx_alg(self.llist, self.start_board)

    # Converts a one dimensional's element index to two dimensional's coordinates
    def num_to_coords(self, num):
        row = num // self.cols
        col = num - row * self.cols 
        return row, col

    def delete_filled_on_start_cells(self, llist):
        for col_head_node in llist.row_nonzero_nodes(llist.head):
            row, col = self.num_to_coords(col_head_node.value - 1)
            if self.start_board[row][col]:
                llist.delete_col(col_head_node)

    def print_progress(self, message, interval):
        new_time = time()
        if (new_time - self.prevtime) >= interval:
            print(message)
            print(f"Time has elapsed: {timedelta(seconds=new_time - self.starttime)}")
            self.prevtime = new_time

    def check_solution_uniqueness(self, solution):
        reflected_solution = self.reflect(solution)
        for sol in [solution, reflected_solution]:  
            if sol in self.solutions:
                return
            for _ in range(3):
                sol = self.rotate(sol)
                if sol in self.solutions:
                    return
        return 1

    def dlx_alg(self, llist, board):
        # If no rows left - all figures are used
        if llist.head.down is llist.head:
            self.print_progress(f"{self.tried_variants_num} variants have tried", 5.0)
            self.tried_variants_num += 1
            # If no columns left - all cells are filled, the solution is found.
            if llist.head.right is llist.head:
                solution = tuple(tuple(row) for row in board)
                if self.check_solution_uniqueness(solution):
                    print(f"The solution № {len(self.solutions) + 1}")
                    self.print_board(solution)
                    self.solutions.add(solution)
                return
        # Search a column with a minimum of intersected rows
        min_col, min_col_sum = self.find_min_col(llist, llist.head)
        # The perfomance optimization - stops branch analyzing if empty columns appears
        if min_col_sum == 0:
            self.tried_variants_num += 1
            return

        intersected_rows = []
        for node in llist.col_nonzero_nodes(min_col):
            intersected_rows.append(node.row_head)
        # Pick one row (the variant of figure) and try to solve puzzle with it
        for selected_row in intersected_rows:
            rows_to_restore = []
            new_board = self.add_posture_to_board(selected_row, board)
            # If some figure is used, any other variants (postures) of this figure
            # could be discarded in this branch
            for posture_num_node in llist.col_nonzero_nodes(llist.head):
                if posture_num_node.value == selected_row.value:
                    rows_to_restore.append(posture_num_node)
                    llist.delete_row(posture_num_node)

            cols_to_restore = []
            for col_node in llist.row_nonzero_nodes(selected_row):
                for row_node in llist.col_nonzero_nodes(col_node.col_head):
                    # Delete all rows which are using the same cell as the picked one,
                    # because only one figure can fill the specific cell
                    rows_to_restore.append(row_node.row_head)
                    llist.delete_row(row_node.row_head)
                # Delete the columns the picked figure fill, they are not
                # needed in this branch anymore
                cols_to_restore.append(col_node.col_head)
                llist.delete_col(col_node.col_head)
            # Pass the shrinked llist and the board with the picked figure added
            # to the next processing
            self.dlx_alg(llist, new_board)

            for row in rows_to_restore:
                llist.insert_row(row)

            for col in cols_to_restore:
                llist.insert_col(col)

    def find_min_col(self, llist, min_col):
        min_col_sum = float("inf")
        for col in llist.row_nonzero_nodes(llist.head):
            tmp = sum(1 for item in llist.col_nonzero_nodes(col))
            if tmp < min_col_sum:
                min_col = col
                min_col_sum = tmp
        return min_col, min_col_sum

    def add_posture_to_board(self, posture_row, prev_steps_result):
        new_board = prev_steps_result.copy()
        for node in self.llist.row_nonzero_nodes(posture_row):
                row, col = self.num_to_coords(node.col_head.value - 1)
                new_board[row][col] = node.row_head.value
        return new_board

    def print_board(self, board):
        for row in board:
            for cell in row:
                print(f"{cell: >3}", end='')
            print()
        print()
        print("#" * 80) 

    def unique_figure_postures(self, named_figures):
        postures = set(named_figures)
        for name, fig in named_figures:
            postures.add((name, self.reflect(fig)))

        all_postures = set(postures)
        for name, posture in postures:
            for _ in range(3):
                posture = self.rotate(posture)
                all_postures.add((name, posture))

        return all_postures
    # Generates entries for all possible positions of every figure's posture.
    # Then the items of these entires will be linked into the 2 dimensional circular linked list
    # The entry looks like:
    # figure's name  {board cells filled by figure}  empty board's cells 
    #            |       | | | | |                       | | |
    #            5 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ................
    def generate_positions(self, postures, rows, cols):
        def apply_posture(name, posture, y, x, wdth, hght):
            # Flattening of 2d list
            line = [cell for row in self.start_board for cell in row]
            # Puts the figure onto the flattened start board
            for r in range(hght):
                for c in range(wdth):
                    if posture[r][c]:
                        num = (r + y) * cols + x + c
                        if line[num]:
                            return
                        line[num] = posture[r][c]
            # And adds name into the beginning
            line.insert(0, name)
            return line
        # makes columns header in a llist
        yield [i for i in range(rows * cols + 1)]

        for name, posture in postures:
            posture_height = len(posture)
            posture_width = len(posture[0])
            for row in range(rows):
                if row + posture_height > rows:
                    break
                for col in range(cols):
                    if col + posture_width > cols:
                        break
                    new_line = apply_posture(name, posture, row, col, posture_width, posture_height)
                    if new_line:
                        yield new_line

    def rotate(self, fig):
        return tuple(zip(*fig[::-1]))

    def reflect(self, fig):
        return tuple(fig[::-1])
```

Comment: Comments mate, comments. This seems a nice piece of code to dive in and comments might've helped.

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer I heard the opinion that comments overloading isn't good as well as a scarce of them. The idea was something like: *"Allow code to speak"*. So, I didn't make a lot of comments, but have tried to write a "speaking code" instead. The hardest part of the program is algorithm, it has comments in key places. And the algorithm has good explanation in the Wikipedia. Also, I read many source codes of big programs, like **CPython** - they are not having a lot of comments to explain everything, only for key things, so I did the same.

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer For example, do the `insert_col` or `delete_col` methods need comments?

Comment: One of the reasons it's hard to get answers to your question is that it's long. Removing those commented out codes shorten it for one thing. One of the non-breaking code reading ways is to write comments after codes `code # comment` so that the code is read and when not understood, you just glance sideways. What i feel lack is the big picture like a docstring to `def dlx_alg(self, llist, board):` . Your linkedlist for example is too long. Compare with [this](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganUnorderedListLinkedLists.html)

Comment: A linkedlist is a common data structure and does not need a lot of deriving, They are the basic tools for solving problems. Memorising how to write good one allows one to focus on the algo at hand. That's another way of reducing the code, putting the focus on the algo part.

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer I looked at the article about **Linked List** you gave. There is a simple linked list, not my case. In my case it is a **interlinked 2-d matrix**, where every node has 4 neighbors: up, down, left, right. And it is customized specially for this program, because the program needs methods to manipulate rows and columns. I didn't find an explanation article about this to give you. May be this will be useful: [Dancing Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links#Implementation)

Comment: agree, the was trying to illustrate that data structs are to be as as simple as possible.

Comment: @MiniMax Hi, are you still working on that? I'd like to review your code, but it requires some questions to understand it, it lacks a lot of comments I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Low Hanging Fruit

I obtained a 27% speed-up with one tiny change.

For this speed-up, I didn't want to wait 2 hours for tests to run, so I used a 3x20 board.  Elapsed times:

- 0:01:44 - before the change
- 0:01:16 - after the change

I'm sure you'd like to know what the change was.  I can't drag it out much more, so here it is.  I added this line to the `Nodes` class:

```
    __slots__ = ('value', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'row_head', 'col_head')
```

This eliminates the `__dict__` member of the `Nodes` objects.  So instead of `self.down` being interpreted as `self.__dict__['down']`, the value referenced is in a predefined "slot" in the `Nodes` object.  Not only do the references become faster, but the object uses less space, which reduces the memory footprint, which increases locality of reference which again helps performance.

(Adding the `__slots__` to `Linked_list_2D` and `Solver` didn't change my performance numbers at all.)

## Interface

```
class Solver():
    def __init__(self, board, figures, rows, cols, figures_naming_start):
        ...
```

This is an "unfriendly" interface.  You have to pass all 5 values to the `Solver()`.  But some of these parameters are redundant.

You've got `board` and you have `rows` and `cols`.  Given a `board`, the `Solver` could determine `rows = len(board)` and `cols = len(board[0])`.  Or given `rows` and `cols`, the `Solver()` could construct an empty board.

`figures_naming_start` is likely always going to be `1`.  Why not use a default value of `1` for that parameter?  Or pass a dictionary to `figures` with the key names the "name" for the figures.  And since `figures` is a predefined set, why not default it to a class constant?

```
class Solver():
    STANDARD_FIGURES = { 'I' : ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
                         'Q' : ((1, 1, 1, 1),
                                (1, 0, 0, 0)),
                         ...
                       }
    def __init__(self, board=None, rows=None, cols=None, figures=STANDARD_FIGURES):
        if board is None:
            board = [[0] * cols for _ in range(len(rows))]
        if rows is None and cols is None:
            rows = len(board)
            cols = len(board[0])
        ...
```

Usage:

```
solver = Solver(rows=3, cols=20)
solver.find_solutions()
```

## Finding Solutions

When a solution is found, it is printed.  What if you wanted to display it in a GUI of some kind, with coloured tiles?

It would be better for `find_solutions()` to `yield solution`, and then the caller could print the solutions, or display them in some fashion, or simply count them:

```
solver = Solver(rows=3, cols=20)
for solution in solver.find_solutions():
    solver.print_board(solution)
```

## Progress

The progress / timing messages should be presented via the `logging` module, where they could be printed, or written to a file, or turned off all together.